# Auto formatting white on dark colours, black on light colours

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was given a macro by a predecessor.

I would like to add automatic colouring of the font (white on dark colours, black on light colours).

I have no experience with visual basic.

```vb
Sub colourProgress()
    Dim c As Word.Cell
    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        For Each c In Selection.Tables(1).Range.Cells
            If IsNumeric(Left(c.Range.Text, Len(c.Range.Text) - 1)) Then
                If Val(c.Range.Text) = 3 Then
                    c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
                ElseIf Val(c.Range.Text) = 4 Then
                    c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorOrange
                End If
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "good") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 176, 80)
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "exceptional") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(148, 55, 257)
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "satisfactory") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "serious") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "concern") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "three or more sub-levels above target") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(148, 55, 257)
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "two sub-levels above target") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBrightGreen
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "one sub-level above target") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 176, 80)
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "on target") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "one sub-level below target") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "two or more sub-levels below target") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
                
            ElseIf c.RowIndex > 1 Then ' set non-numeric in row 2 and down to White
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorWhite
            End If
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried adding

```
c.Font.Color = white
```

Comment: With Word, learn to use styles for fomatting, even when coding. Word is very much built around styles. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview

Answer (score 0):

When you type an object name followed by a period in the VBA editor IntelliSense will show you a list of valid options to follow the period:

[image]

`Font` would not have been in that list. However, you can see from the code you already have that an object called `Range` has a text property. If `Range` has text, you can logically conclude that it must also have a `Font` property.

[image]

To set the font colour to automatic you would need something like:

`c.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdAuto`

However, rather than set the text color for individual cells you would be better to set the color for the entire table. If your document is formatted correctly there should be no need to use code to change the font color, otherwise it can be done with code like this:

`Selection.Tables(1).Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdAuto`

Answer (score 0):

For example, provided the strings in your code are all that's in the cells:

```
Sub ColourProgress()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim c As Word.Cell, BckClr As Long, FntClr As Long
With Selection
  If .Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    For Each c In .Tables(1).Range.Cells
      Select Case Split(c.Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
        Case 3:                                       BckClr = wdColorYellow:       FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        Case 4:                                       BckClr = wdColorOrange:       FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        Case "good":                                  BckClr = RGB(0, 176, 80):     FntClr = wdColorWhite
        Case "exceptional":                           BckClr = RGB(148, 55, 257):   FntClr = wdColorWhite
        Case "satisfactory":                          BckClr = wdColorYellow:       FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        Case "serious":                               BckClr = wdColorRed:          FntClr = wdColorWhite
        Case "concern":                               BckClr = RGB(255, 192, 0):    FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        Case "three or more sub-levels above target": BckClr = RGB(148, 55, 257):   FntClr = wdColorWhite
        Case "two sub-levels above target":           BckClr = wdColorBrightGreen:  FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        Case "one sub-level above target":            BckClr = RGB(0, 176, 80):     FntClr = wdColorWhite
        Case "on target":                             BckClr = wdColorYellow:       FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        Case "one sub-level below target":            BckClr = RGB(255, 192, 0):    FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        Case "two or more sub-levels below target":   BckClr = wdColorRed:          FntClr = wdColorWhite
        Case Else:                                    BckClr = wdColorAutomatic:    FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
      End Select
      c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = BckClr
      c.Range.Font.Color = FntClr
    Next c
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. The code looks a lot cleaner and neater than what was given to me. I tried it and it doesn't seem to work though. But with your help and @Timothy-Rylatt I managed to fix the original code to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I think this works now.

```
Sub colourProgress()
    Dim c As Word.Cell
    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        For Each c In Selection.Tables(1).Range.Cells
          If InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "good") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    c.Range.Font.Color = WdColorBlack
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "exceptional") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(148, 55, 257)
    c.Range.Font.Color = WdColorBlack
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "satisfactory") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
    c.Range.Font.Color = WdColorBlack
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "serious") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
    c.Range.Font.Color = WdColorBlack
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "concern") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    c.Range.Font.Color = WdColorBlack
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "three or more sub-levels above target") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(148, 55, 257)
    c.Range.Font.Color = WdColorBlack
         ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "two sub-levels above target") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBrightGreen
    c.Range.Font.Color = WdColorBlack
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "one sub-level above target") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    c.Range.Font.Color = WdColorBlack
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "on target") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
    c.Range.Font.Color = WdColorBlack
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "one sub-level below target") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    c.Range.Font.Color = WdColorBlack
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(c.Range.Text), "two or more sub-levels below target") > 0 Then
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
    c.Range.Font.Color = WdColorBlack
         ElseIf Len(c.Range.Text) < 3 Then
                      c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray25
          ElseIf c.RowIndex > 1 Then ' set non-numeric in row 2 and down to White
                c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorWhite
    c.Range.Font.Color = WdColorBlack
          End If
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I posted before works just fine if the strings in your code are all that's in the cells.

A better and more robust approach than changing the font on just the cells currently containing the darker shading would be:

```
Sub ColourProgress()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim c As Word.Cell, BckClr As Long, FntClr As Long
With Selection
  If .Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    For Each c In .Tables(1).Range.Cells
      BckClr = wdColorAutomatic:    FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
      With c.Range
        If Split(.Text, vbCr)(0) = 3 Then BckClr = wdColorYellow: FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        If Split(.Text, vbCr)(0) = 4 Then BckClr = wdColorOrange: FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        If InStr(.Text, "good") > 0 Then BckClr = RGB(0, 176, 80): FntClr = wdColorWhite
        If InStr(.Text, "exceptional") > 0 Then BckClr = RGB(148, 55, 257): FntClr = wdColorWhite
        If InStr(.Text, "satisfactory") > 0 Then BckClr = wdColorYellow: FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        If InStr(.Text, "serious") > 0 Then BckClr = wdColorRed: FntClr = wdColorWhite
        If InStr(.Text, "concern") > 0 Then BckClr = RGB(255, 192, 0): FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        If InStr(.Text, "three or more sub-levels above target") > 0 Then BckClr = RGB(148, 55, 257): FntClr = wdColorWhite
        If InStr(.Text, "two sub-levels above target") > 0 Then BckClr = wdColorBrightGreen: FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        If InStr(.Text, "one sub-level above target") > 0 Then BckClr = RGB(0, 176, 80): ntClr = wdColorWhite
        If InStr(.Text, "on target") > 0 Then BckClr = wdColorYellow: FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        If InStr(.Text, "one sub-level below target") > 0 Then BckClr = RGB(255, 192, 0): FntClr = wdColorAutomatic
        If InStr(.Text, "two or more sub-levels below target") > 0 Then BckClr = wdColorRed: FntClr = wdColorWhite
      End With
      c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = BckClr
      c.Range.Font.Color = FntClr
    Next c
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This ensures both the shading *and* the font are updated if the cell contents change.